# How to make div shadow come over its children?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I want the inner shadow of my div to come over it's content (please note that I don't simply want the image to have an inner shadow, I have a much more complicated scrollable div with so many children this is just a minimal example.

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Vitalii Chmovzh answer, but in case you don't want any space by padding.

So just use this for your `img` tag.

```
img{
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Without changing sizes of your box model.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp9pz9w0/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add padding for a shadow amount.

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

See working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f0qasdo6/

UPD: Another working example without changing `div` size:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Downside of this approach is that you will not be able to click on the content inside the div, so it can be used to add an effect to non-interactible blocks.

See fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/r3t2p2cw/

Comment: as I've said I want the shadow to come over the children. I don't want to change the size of the container.

Comment: do you want to give shadow to image?

Comment: @ladybug I have another idea. Let me check it really quick.

Comment: @Nihal As I've said in the question: `please note that I don't simply what the image to have inner shadow`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this is that the image gets rendered over the shadow.

Try this,

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

img{
  display: block;
}

div::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your image doesn't work for me. Here is the solution:

```
div {
  width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tp9pz9w0/7/